# Iptable rules for SMTP NAT to borrow static public IP of data center server

Tags: iptables, nat, ptr-record

I'd like to run my own mail server on my (decent) home ISP connection rather than trusting my emails to any data center provider - mostly because I already have a machine running.

Although in practice, my public IP never changes, my ISP would not provide me with a proper static IP for which I could adapt the reverse DNS PTR record without switching to a business plan which comes with a significant markup. As a result, emails transferred by my server are treated as spam - obviously.

So I thought I could *borrow* a public IP of a small VPS (of which I can control the PTR record) by chaining two iptables NATs. Using NATs rather than a SMTP relay, does not impair the end-to-end TLS encryption.

However, I'm struggling setting up the NAT(s) as follows. Each machine has a single network interface only and I plan to limit the NATing to the TCP/25 port as I do not want to run all my private traffic through the Relay/VPS.

```
Home Server 1.2.3.4             Relay 5.6.7.8             Recipient Mailserver 10.11.12.13
[home.server.mydomain]          [relay.mydomain]          [mail.recipientdomain]

OUTPUT/MASQUERADE       <=>      FORWARD/MASQUERADE    <=>  INPUT
```

For testing the setup, I am using netcat for now and run a firewalled placeholder Mailserver 10.11.12.13 which only accepts traffic on port 25 originating from the Relay 5.6.7.8.

Yet, somehow I fail to wrap my mind around the iptable rules/NAT concept and am hoping for some hints (ip forwarding is enabled in sysclt on the relay):

Home Server 1.2.3.4

```
-A OUTPUT -t nat -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.6.7.8:25
-A POSTROUTING -t nat -d 5.6.7.8 -p tcp --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE
```

Relay 5.6.7.8

```
-A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 1.2.3.4 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE
```

Mailserver 10.11.12.13

```
-A INPUT -s 5.6.7.8 -j ACCEPT # for testing
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

With these, the Home Server is able to reach port 25 on the relay but nothing else:

$(mailserver)> nc -ltp 25
$(homeserver)> nc 10.11.12.13 25

Any advice highly appreciated.
Disclaimer: My idea might still have some security implications I haven't thought about yet.

Comment: Just run the mail server on the small VPS.

Comment: Well, this would be the standard. Yet, the point is to have them hosted on-premis rather than on any random VPS.

Answer (score 1):

Run the mail server on the VPS.

Encrypt data in motion by enabling TLS for all protocols.

Encrypt data at rest with disk encryption. If you don't trust the provider, consider a more complex setup of doing the encryption yourself, and entering the key on instance boot.

Back up data and get it off site to home and a different provider's archival storage.

Do not NAT. Consider implementing IPv6 instead.

---

Should you value running a mail server at home, switch to business service. Typically, that is the price ISPs extract for static addressing and to remove their SMTP filtering.

IPv6 has more than enough addresses for every residential customer to get a /48. And competent IPAM systems will reliably give a customer their assigned prefix. (No, this is not necessarily MAC based, because non-MAC DHCPv6 unique identifiers (DUIDs) exist.)  But that doesn't mean ISPs *promise* static addresses. My home has been stable but renumbered once for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: Thanks; didn't think about IPv6. Will look into that. If I'm not mistaken, these are "practically" static IPs - at least the one tied to your MAC address is, I believe. But aren't the implications of the PTR record the same as with IPv4?

Comment: Customer stable IPv6 prefixes are possible but not guaranteed on all ISP service offerings. And running "servers" is generally against residential terms of service. More basic, my point was there are ways to work around not trusting a hosting provider that likely provide more reliable service than NAT hacks on a residential link.

Answer (score 1):

- Run a VPN service on the VPS
- Make your local mail server at home its VPN client. Configure it so it has static VPN address
- Mail server must have a route to the VPN server via local home internet (to be able to establish a connection), the rest (a default route) must be routed via VPN
- On the VPS make a SNAT from VPN addresses via its internet-facing interface, and make a DNAT for SMTP port to the inside-vpn address of mail server

Notice this differs sligtly from what you asked. You wanted to only route email via VPS, this way you'll route all mail server traffic via VPS. But I think it's better, because for the world your mail server will appear as if it is living on the VPS, just somewhat slower.

All of this is easy to accomplish with cheap Linux VPS and OpenVPN.

Essentially you are creating another (VPN) interface on your VPS machine and it becomes a router, a VPN and a mail server inside of it becomes its LAN.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's definitely the way to go as it lifts the issue of having just a single interface. It's basically a standard NAT with a single port forward. Would have been my second option. Still wondering whether my exercise in question is technically possible in the first place.

Comment: Nothing prevents a NAT with just a single L3 interface. If you're near the machine doing this (in the same L2 segment), no problem, set it as default gateway and go as usual. If you want to do this with a machine far away from you (routed), the only way to go is to translate *both* addresses at once. This is possible, but I'm not sure that's what you want. If you don't mind drawing a network diagram, I'll add another answer to cover this case. But don't consider implementing it; your mail server will see all mails as coming from your NAT box address. Very inconvenient for fighting spam.

Comment: I need to emphasize. The problem is not to have second interface or a second IP address. NAT will happily work with just a signle interface and a single IP address. The problem is routing on the side "behind the NAT". You'll not be able to easily route back packets that were routed to you from the NAT.